# Change text color of old date using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I am using javascript to display a dashboard with various charts and graphs and when you click a chart you can drill down and see information about it.

At the bottom I also have a date of when the charts were last updated.

How can change the text color of the text when the 'last updated' date has passed?

I could do it in C# with the following code (something like it, didn't test it), but not sure on how to go about it using javascript.

```
if(text.Date < DateTime.Now)
{
    text.Date.backcolor == Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: _"when the 'last updated' date has passed?"_ - Won't this be 100% of the time? Surely you don't ever have 'last updated' in the future?

Comment: @nnnnnn, sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant if my last updated was a few days or months ago...it wouldn't be updated daily.

Comment: For any one to usefully answer this I think they'll need to see your html. Generally, you can add a class name to the `this.classname = "late"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var dt =  document.getElementById("yourDate"); //get your date
var today = new Date(); //get date today
if(dt.value <  today )
{
    dt.style.color="red";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to answer if you disclosed how you are putting the date there and what format it is in.

Otherwise check out the Date object in javascript.  It could be as simple as:

```
var oldDate = new Date(unix_timestamp); // you'd provide this from your db?
if(oldDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime() < 0)
    document.getElementById('your_date_element?').style.color = 'red';
```

If you're putting the date there via php or something, you could simply change the output color at that time using a php solution ( strtotime and time(), for example)

EDIT: but yeah that'll always be the case lol.